# Actions position on cards

Tags: actions, cards

Is there a best practice or a guideline saying that actions on cards should be located on the bottom of the card for touchable screens ?

Are there actions types that should be located on the top of the card ?

Thank you for your replies !

Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [Material Design suggests](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-actions) that "supplemental actions within the card are... typically placed at the bottom of the card [on mobile]".

The reason for having actions at the bottom is that you scan from the top to the bottom, gathering information about the content. When you get to the bottom you have all the information you need to decide which action to take. If it was at the top you would see the actions first, and would therefore need to reposition your gaze back to the top.

Actions are ideally placed to the right of the card because this is area falls within the majority of right-handed users - i.e. the majority of users' - most easy-to-reach-with-thumb area.

Given this reasoning it feels like it might make sense to place actions at the top of the card if it is preceded by enough information to make a decision. For example, if the card has a title in the top left and it is a section name used elsewhere in the system it might make sense to have a link to "See more", or to drill down in the top right.